# Importing Library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opencsv

I have an Eclipse project where I imported the library "OpenCSV" as an external JAR. The library is now shown in my project under "referenced libraries".

However, when I call:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvPath));
```

Eclipse throws an error saying that the constructor CSVReader is not defined. csvPath is of type String.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Screenshot

[image: My workspace]

Comment: What version of the lib did you import? Are you sure that constructor is present in that version?

Comment: Hi @tobias_k yes you're right, apparently the latest update has the constructor taking a 'Reader', but java tells me it's not possible to initiate such type..

Comment: That's because `Reader` is an abstract class. However, `FileReader` _is_ a `Reader`, so this should not be a problem. Maybe there's another class with the same name on your class path?

Comment: @tobias_k I've added a screenshot of my workspace

Comment: you have to add try and catch

Comment: Is it fine if I throw an IOException in the metehod signature instead? @snow8261

Comment: you can do it as well

Comment: On a sidenote, capitalizing method names isn't recommended.

Comment: @snow8261 my method signature now is: public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> ReadCSV(String csvPath) throws IOException but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be mistaken (I don't use this library and don't know history of its package names) but it looks like `autoEvoSuite` is your own package.

If that is the case <strike>then you have *class name conflict*</strike> (actually there is no conflict, you are just using wrong class) since your class is also named `CSVReader` so inside method `readCVS` you are not calling constructor of `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader`, but constructor of your own class `autoEvoSuite.CSVReader`, and since your class doesn't have

```
public CSVReader(FileReade reader){...}
```

constructor, compiler informs you about this problem.

To solve this problem consider renaming your class, or be explicit and say which class exactly you want to use by writing its full-package-name like

```
au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader reader = new au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader(new FileReader(csvPath));
```

Comment: Yes, of course... Should have seen that myself, but thank you so much! :) Fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

you have to try and catch FileNotFoundException and see the code below.

```
public FileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(new FileInputStream(fileName));
}
```

you can modify it like following

```
   try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvPath));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: you can throw IOException in the metehod signature as well

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a constructor for your own class `CSVReader` that doesn't exist! Either rename your class and create a new instance of `au.com.bytecode.opencsv`, or delete the respective line, make sure you import `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader`, and re-create the line.

Alternatively - but I'm unsure whether this is what you'd want - you can make your `CSVReader` (optimally under another name), extend `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader` and override the respective constructor.

I guess your problem was caused when you used auto-complete for `CSVReader` and didn't pick the class from the right package?

Comment: @DarioP this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the relevant JAR in the project's Build Path in order to have it built.

Your Java Project (Right Click)--> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add JARs/Add External JARs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[My full solution is listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626457/noclassdeffounderror-com-opencsv-csvwriter/41538328#41538328), try working with [CSVParser instead](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html), which is available from the Apache Commons and works much more readily!